# Lambda in multiple type object expression

Tags: lambda, kotlin, object-expression

I'm provided a class `Foo` which does some `work()`:

```
open class Foo() {      
    fun work(x: T) {
        // Effects taking place here  
    }
}
```

And I am also provided (but by someone else) a method `useJob()` which consumes an object of interface type `Bar` having a single method `doJob()`.

```
fun useJob(bar: Bar)

interface Bar {
    fun doJob(x: T)
}
```

It turns out `Foo.work()` does the job expected by `useJob()`. However, in order to have `useJob()` calling `work()`, I need to write something like that:

```
useJob(object : Foo(), Bar { fun doJob(x: T) { work(x) } })
```

Is there any way to use a lambda instead of this blob?

EDIT: @jrtapsell comment made me realize Foo is actually open.

Comment: Can foo be open?

Comment: @jrtapsell yes it can

Comment: Do you need the `Bar` interface, or could you just have `fun useJob(bar: (T) -> Unit)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Bar` were defined in Java, you could write

```
useJob { Foo().work(x) }
```

or

```
val foo = Foo()
useJob { foo.work(x) }
```

to avoid constructing `Foo()` every time in case `useJob` calls its argument multiple times.

But

> [note that this feature works only for Java interop; since Kotlin has proper function types, automatic conversion of functions into implementations of Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary and therefore unsupported.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions)

Without moving `Bar` to Java, I'd go with joecks' solution or define an overload of `useJob` (possibly as extension method). Which is better depends on how many methods like `useJob` you have and how many uses for each.

Answer (score 4):

Well the easiest way to achieve this would be by using a factory method that creates a instance of Bar and accepts a function call:

```
fun job(func: (Param) -> Unit) : Bar = object: Bar { 
   override fun doJob(x: Param) = func(x)
}
```

then you can use

```
useJob( job { Foo().work(it) } )
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem, that `useJob` is expecting an interface instead of a function type directly. This way you can only do:

```
val bar = object : Bar {
    override fun doJob(x: String) = Foo().work(x)
}

useJob(bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
// Mock class
class Param

// Provided code
open class Foo<T> {
    fun work(x: T) {
        // Effects taking place here
    }
}

fun useJob(bar: Bar) {}

interface Bar {
    fun doJob(x: Param)
}

// New code
object FooBar: Foo<Param>(), Bar {
    override fun doJob(x: Param) = work(x)
    fun use() = useJob(this)
}

fun x() {
    FooBar.use()
}
```

It requires a bit more code for the FooBar object, but it cleans up the call sites.

Comment: Nice code. Actually `Param` was a typo in `Bar` and `T` is a defined type, not a genericity parameter.